# Why python app won't close on mouse click?

Tags: python, mouse

I have recently started to learn python. I have been working on simple clicker project. There are no errors in project. It does not run noclick function. My goal is to have a keybind that shutsdown the clicker. Take a look:

```py
def noclick():
    run = 1
    exit()

def clicker():
    while(run == 1):
        mouse.click("left")
        time.sleep(float(cap))
    mouse.on_double_click (clicker)
    mouse.on_right_click (noclick)
    cap = input("Time gaps between clicks: ")
    print("Double click to activate")
```

Comment: Does it run clicker()?

Comment: Yes. It runs it perfectly. I can't close after clicker()

Answer (score 1):

Functions bodies should be intended, so rather than

```
def noclick():
run = 0
exit()
```

you should have

```
def noclick():
    run = 0
    exit()
```

Same for `clicker` function.

Answer (score 0):

You must change run value to 1. But firstly define run value globally. After, call the click function:

```
run=1
clicker()
```

Comment: I have it later in code. Just did not wanted to post everything here.